RTL Text Printing Incorrectly in PDF Generated with Mixed Hebrew and English and Numbers
I'm using Puppeteer Sharp in a .NET Web API to generate PDFs that include product names with mixed Hebrew and English text. However, the text is not rendering correctly in the generated PDF. Specifically, if a product name contains both Hebrew text and numbers, the order of the characters gets mixed up.
For example, the product name (100) 2024 Hebrewtext  should print as (100) 2024 Hebrewtext, but it prints as 100) 2024 Hebrewtext)
Nuget package --> PuppeteerSharp & version ---> 18.0.4
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePdf()
{
    try
    {
         var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions { Headless = true };
         var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
         await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
         using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);
         using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
         
         
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product { Id = 1, Name = "(100) 2024 Hebrewtext" },
        };
 
        var htmlTemplate =//htmlTemplate
 
        string htmlContent = GenerateHtml(htmlTemplate, products);
        await page.SetContentAsync(htmlContent);
 
        var pdfOptions = new PdfOptions
        {
            Format = PuppeteerSharp.Media.PaperFormat.A4,
            PrintBackground = true
        };
 
        var pdfStream = await page.PdfStreamAsync(pdfOptions);
        var fileName = "invoice.pdf";
        var filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\", fileName);
        
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await pdfStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        
        return File(filePath, "application/pdf", fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

How can I ensure that the product name with mixed Hebrew text ,English text ,Numbers and Special characters prints correctly in the generated PDF using Puppeteer Sharp.
